# Android: Clickable span selects the text in textview

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, spannablestring

So Im using this Clickable span as well as Underline Span to make the parts of my text clickable, but whenever I touch any of those "clickable" parts of the text, the listener does gets called but it selects the text as well. Just like a selector, Now even if this is a default feature with clickable spans, it should disappear on its own but rather I have to touch randomly on the screen to make it disappear. Can anyone please set me to the right track here? thanks
[image]

```
spannableString.setSpan(underlineSpan1,60,text.length()-1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        ClickableSpan clickableSpan=new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this,"Dummy text",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
        };
        spannableString.setSpan(clickableSpan,39,55, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        tvTerms.setText(spannableString);
        tvTerms.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Add this line at the end:

```
textView.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

May be this will help.

Comment: OK so that does work for now but from your comment, now I know its called Highlighting of the text. Thanks for that, Im just wondering if there is a proper way to sort of un-highlight the text so that we don't have to workaround through transparent colour?

Comment: This feature of `setHighlightColor` was meant for something like how you doing on top, by default Clickable span highlights the text.. I would prefer if you'd used setOnClickListener() on your textview then it would probably not have been highlighted at all, but it would not be on a particular text but on a whole textview. Another way is to have different text view but obviously it's not concise and effects performance too. Now, it's upto you how you want to use it.. Personally for something what you're doing, I prefer to have different textviews alligned.